# Word : se quedaban

Tags: uso-de-palabras

Please read the below sentence:

> Ya que los mayores iban a el campo a trabajar, los niños **se quedaban** y jugaban juntos.

In English it means: Since the older went to work in the field, the children **stayed** and played together.  (Correct??)

But "quedar" can also mean "to meet (citarse)", so here can we say "se quedaban" also mean "they met together" (ie. "se" is *'Con valor recíproco'*) ??

Comment: the verb "quedar" can't mean "to meet" when it's used in a pronominal way. So if you say "*los niños se quedaban*" it can't mean "to meet" but *"los niños quedaban*" can mean that.

Comment: @Javi: so does it mean if we use "se", once it is a pronominal, it can't be "recíproco"??

Comment: This "se" is not "con valor recíproco". It would be reciprocal if the action were done to each other. But it's not the case because you can't "stay to each other".

Comment: But "quedar" can also mean "to meet". So can't "se quedar" mean "they meet together"?

Comment: "quedar" can mean "to meet" but it would be more precise to say that it can mean "to arrange to meet". "quedarse" never means "to meet" because you can't "arrange each other to meet".

Answer (score 3):

The correct sentence is the first one:

> Since the older went to work in the field, the children stayed and
>   played together.

To get the second meaning (to meet) the sentence in spanish needs to be something similar to this:

> Ya que los mayores iban a el campo a trabajar, los niños quedaban para
>   jugar juntos.

Also, in Spanish `a el` is contracted into `al`, the same happens to `de el`, which becomes `del`:

> Ya que los mayores iban AL campo...

Hope this helps you.